# scheduler kendo not posting datasourcerequest

Tags: kendo-ui, scheduler

I am using Kendo UI with ASP.NET MVC. I am tying to use the Scheduler control. The Scheduler control is not posting the DataSourceRquest object back to the controller when I am writing

dataSouce.filter(criteria);

The criteria in this case is the filters populated using AND operator. The above line is not posting any filters back to the controller.

Also, even the scheduler's next date and previous date button are also not posting any date filters.

Is this expected behavior or am I missing something?

Conroller

```
public ActionResult GetList([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
   return Json(_service.GetList(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Javascript

```
dataSouce.filter(criteria); // Where dataSource is Kendo Scheduler dataSource
```

And criteria object in console looks like this --> Object{ logic: "and", filters: Array[1] }

But nothing is posted back to the MVC action method??

Comment: [dataSource.filter](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource#configuration-filter) should work - so without some code snippet, I am afraid that nobody will be able to find out source of error.

Comment: @Ademar: Can you tell me if the filter() method makes a call to the server (MVC action method) with filters? Also, can you tell me if the scheduler does paging serve side or client side?

Comment: I think no it will not - you just modified your filter. Anyway view is not automatically changed, you need use [view](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/scheduler#methods-view) method. If you want request your server method, you will need refresh whole dataSource. 
And about paging - Actually I am not working with schedulars, so not have much experiences with them - but it will depends on your settings like in other components (grid for example). (It can be client or server)

Comment: I have found [this example](http://jsbin.com/uNoKOFu/1/edit?html,js,output) look on it, it can helps you.

Comment: you can do this [filter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34780211/using-or-condition-while-filtering-kendo-grid/34780797#34780797) without accessing the controller

Comment: I want scheduler to get the data for a month only (when in month view). Then, If a previous month is selected or navigated to prev or next - another call should be made to fetch the data for specific month view. That's how I expected the paging to work in scheduler but It seems the scheduler doesn't do paging ...it just gets alll data and then client paging is done. This means a lot of data being fetched when no required.